502 Error When Accessing AKS via Application Gateway Ingress in Azure Private network
I have configured an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) with an Application Gateway in a private network setting. To facilitate communication between them, I've set up an Application Gateway Ingress Controller. There are no public IPs involved as everything is contained within a private network. I have established network peering between the Virtual Networks (VNets) of the AKS and the Application Gateway, in addition to peering from AKS to the Application Gateway and vice versa.
To test the ingress service, I deployed pods and set up an ingress component in one of these pods, marking the private IP setting as true in the configuration. I executed this configuration using the Kubernetes controller. Upon deployment, a backend pool was automatically added to the Application Gateway, indicating that the ingress controller is operational and the pod is running successfully. I have confirmed the functionality of the pod through tests.
However, when I attempt to access the service via the private IP of the Application Gateway, I encounter a 502 error, suggesting that the Application Gateway is unable to communicate with AKS. I have verified that the backend pools in the Application Gateway are correctly mapped to the ingress of the pods.
What steps can I take to diagnose and resolve this 502 error?
ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: prd-pt-ui-app-ingress
  namespace: prd
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: "/"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prd-pt-ui-app-service
            port:
              number: 80

Backend pools:

Health Probe:


Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Are you using AGIC?

@Hackerman, yes.. AGIC has been properly set.. An ingress changed i do in the AKS are reflecting in the gateway. but the other way is not working Arr gw to AKS..

The health probe in the screenshot you provided is showing that backend instances are unhealthy. This means that the Application Gateway's health probe is not receiving a successful health response from the backend pool, which could be the reason for the 502 error you're encountering when trying to access the service. Kindly share few more details. This seems like troubleshooting question.

Kindly go through these documents once -   Troubleshooting bad gateway errors in Application Gateway

Troubleshoot backend health issues in Application Gateway


As displayed in your last screenshot, there is no healthy backend assigned to the pool and therefore no requests can be forwarded to the pool (i.e., you receive the 502 error).
You need to ensure that the health check from the pool is successful first of all (i.e., returning 200-399 code).
